# Why wont my new HDD boot w/ fresh install of Ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I just purchased a new HDD to replace a failed one... seagate 500gb sata drive... I installed Ubuntu 18 from USB and the drive won't boot at all w/ auto install I never see grub... if i manually partition for legacy mode I made 500mb boot partition, 8196mb swap  (2x RAM) and the rest for root... then I remove USB, change boot order, and this time I see grub but when booting, it freezes on Loading initial ramdisk... and stops there....

My computer is prob decade old... BIOS is biostar phoenix award workstation BIOS, don't think it even has UEFI mode... It always ran win XP until now.

Please help me get my desktop working again!!!

Comment: i have uploaded my bootinfo report http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hCSHQbnqcp/

Comment: UEFI became the PC standard about 5 years ago with Windows 8. Older computers will be BIOS, but you may be able to use gpt, but not requried. You show advanced LVM partitioning on sdb. Do you have drive set for AHCI in BIOS, not IDE nor RAID. Some old systems only boot from first 137GB of a drive. So either / (root) has to be entirely in beginning of drive with rest as /home or a /boot partition at beginning of drive. Often better not to use LVM unless an advanced user, for a server or if you must have encryption.

Comment: OK so it wasn't working so i reinstalled ubuntu without LVM option and this is my new bootinfo summary http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ysmsrt3zbv/

Comment: Same question, is AHCI on in BIOS, not IDE nor RAID? Often better to use 25GB / (root) and rest as /home or a /mnt/data partition. You will not see grub with one install, but should be able to get menu by holding shift key from BIOS until menu appears. Have you then tried recovery mode? What brand/model system? Some need boot parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what ahci is but i turned off fast boot and smart mode or whatever... I'll try adding /home on my next install cause I've reinstalled 100x already... atm I'm chroot apt updating everything before trying to reboot... but previously i tried booting in recovery mode and it froze on loading initial ramdisk... I'll try turning quiet mode off and see if it gives more info

Answer (score 0):

i got it working!!! I'm not sure what i did differently.... but this time i installed unencrypted and without LVM and after install i chroot apt update/upgrade to update all files then ran boot-repair and at grub menu selected recovery and it booted instantly... super happy my desktop is working again!!